# ZedGraph filling areas

Tags: c#, graphics, zedgraph

I am using the ZedGraph control and want to fill one side of the graph function with some color and other side with other color.

```
 PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
 list1.Add(0, 4);
 list1.Add(4, 0);
 LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("y(n)", list1, Color.Red, SymbolType.Diamond);

 //This filling bottom side.
 myCurve.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(113, 255, 0, 0), 90F);

 //How to fill the top side?
```

Comment: Can't you just add one fill as the whole chart's background, and then second just as you did, as the fill for your curve? That Should do the trick. Or maybe you have something else on mind?

Comment: actually I did like you said, but I need to fill area thats formed with multiple line intersections (some polygon),can I fill some polygon area in Zed graph?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Is the only way to modify source code?

Comment: Is here where we should modify the code https://github.com/lightweightlabs/zedgraph-lw/blob/master/source/ZedGraph/Fill.cs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not very clear on what you're asking - but hopefully the below will help. You said in comments

> Can I fill some polygon area in Zedgraph?

So here's how...

```
var zed = new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl { Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill };

var poly = new ZedGraph.PolyObj
{
    Points = new[]
    {
        new ZedGraph.PointD(0, 0),
        new ZedGraph.PointD(0.5, 1),
        new ZedGraph.PointD(1, 0.5),
        new ZedGraph.PointD(0, 0)
    },
    Fill = new ZedGraph.Fill(Color.Blue),
    ZOrder = ZedGraph.ZOrder.E_BehindCurves
};

var poly1 = new ZedGraph.PolyObj
{
    Points = new[]
    {
        new ZedGraph.PointD(1, 0),
        new ZedGraph.PointD(0.25, 1),
        new ZedGraph.PointD(0.5, 0),
        new ZedGraph.PointD(1, 0)
    },
    Fill = new ZedGraph.Fill(Color.Red),
    ZOrder = ZedGraph.ZOrder.E_BehindCurves
};

zed.GraphPane.AddCurve("Line", new[] { 0.0, 1.0 }, new[] { 0.0, 1.0 }, Color.Green);
zed.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(poly1);
zed.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(poly);
```

Results in

[image]

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction!

<sub>([Code in VB as requested](http://pastebin.com/jsFB1jxP) via http://converter.telerik.com/ - no guarentee of the VB code working or even compiling!)</sub>

Comment: Could you please post an analog of the example in vb.net. I think this is really helpful for everybody.

Comment: <strike>Via http://converter.telerik.com/... http://pastebin.com/jsFB1jxP... I haven't used VB in years so I can't guarantee the validity.</strike> Question updated.